# Strange behavior of bootstrap's responsive design

Tags: css, layout, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, media-queries

I have my own css with `@media` queries. Sometimes (if I scale the size of browser up and then shrink it back) the page has strange margin right (the **navbar** is `static-top` => maximized):

[image: right side of the page]

All element's `outerWidth(true)` are max of the navbar's width. Even window.outerWidth = **400px**. The page on the screenshot is about **600px**

Where could the white field right come from? 
If I shrink the page back **slowly** - this field is just about **10px**, not about **200px** like on the screenshot. Or even if very slow -> no such margin at all. If the page is opened in the tight (small) browser window, there is no problem. So the problem (with **Google Chrome**) is in resizing the browser window. In **FireFox** the problem is also static (slow shrinking the browser window creates the "margin")

Here is screenshot from Safari: `<body>` element selected, so the strange white field is right.

[image]

### Update 1:

deleting my custom css doesn't effect. Still the same issue.

### Update 2:

the problem is caused by the `file chose input field` on a button below. **How shrink it to 0 size?**

### Update 3:

**solved**: add `display: none;` to the `file input field`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add `display: none;` style to the **file input field**